# Changing Datasource of layer in mxd using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to change the datasource of a layer in mxd by programmatically using ArcPy, I have write some code and executed but not getting any results. Please suggest me how to modify my code for results.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\Users\_gis_dev_gds\Desktop\ForDataSource\India_Admin0.mxd")
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths("C:\Users\_gis_dev_gds\Desktop\ForDataSource\IND_adm","C:\Users\_gis_dev_gds\Desktop\ForDataSource\IND_rds")
```

Comment: In Python, be careful of the \.  Either change all your \ to / or preface your strings with r to indicate a literal.  r"C:\Users_gis_dev_gds\Desktop\ForDataSource\India_Admin0.mxd"

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems with your code snippet:

First try changing:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\Users\_gis_dev_gds\Desktop\ForDataSource\India_Admin0.mxd")
```

to:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\_gis_dev_gds\Desktop\ForDataSource\India_Admin0.mxd")
```

and do the same for your other paths.

Then at the end add:

```
mxd.save()
```